# qb64 unable to load image using _putimage, I&

Tags: image, qb64

I'm trying to load an image for the title of my game instead of ASCII for my title, whenever I try to run it, it gives me an error.

I've tried the multiple ways QB64 suggest you load images, but it says the same thing
 it says that _putimage is an illegal command

```
menu:
CLS
PRINT
i& = _LOADIMAGE("FOrest.jpg")
_PUTIMAGE , i&
PRINT ""
PRINT "What Will Your Heros Name be?:";
Name$ = Ask$(5, 1, CSRLIN, POS(0), 11, 0)
CLS
check_1% = 0 'placeholder for debuggingg
COLOR 15, 0
PRINT Name$ + "How Old will Your Hero be?: ";: age% = VAL(Ask$(3, 0, CSRLIN, POS(0), 15, 0))
'INPUT "", age%
```

I expect that it load my image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Code to load forest.jpg:

```
SCREEN _NEWIMAGE(640, 480, 32)
CLS , _RGB(0, 255, 0)
i& = _LOADIMAGE("FOREST.JPG")
IF i& = -1 THEN PRINT "invalid image": END
_PUTIMAGE (0, 0), i&, 0
END
```